# Compressing messages sent between Erlang nodes

Tags: erlang

I am writing a distributed Erlang application where several nodes are connected via a network with limited bandwidth.  Thus, I would like to be able to minimize the size of the packets sent across the network when processes on different nodes send each other messages.

From http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html, I understand that the Erlang distribution mechanism uses erlang:term_to_binary/1,2 internally to convert Erlang messages to the external binary format that is sent over the network.  Now, term_to_binary/2 supports several options that are useful for reducing the size of the binaries (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1), including a compression option as well as the ability to choose a minor version with more efficient encoding of floats.

I would like to be able to tell the distribution mechanism to use both of these options every time it sends a message over the network.  In other words, I would like to be able to specify the Options list that the distribution mechanism calls term_to_binary with.  However, I have not been able to find any documentation on this subject.  Is this possible to do?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: do you want to make the compression options configurable ? If yes then you should some kind of configuration file containing erlang terms and use "file:consult" module.

Comment: Yes, I would like this to be configurable, and storing this information in a file that is processed with file:consult, as you suggest, would certainly work.  However, my main question is how to actually make the distribution mechanism accept the options that I specify in order to turn on compression - this is what I haven't been able to find any documentation on.

Comment: How would you pattern match your data if it is compressed ?

Comment: Check if this link gives you any insight:: http://groups.google.com/group/erlang-programming/browse_thread/thread/6080ddfa72b6d708/c9b3c71dbddb998c?lnk=gst&q=node+to+node+message+passing#c9b3c71dbddb998c

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I think I need to clarify the problem. Assume we have two processes, A and B, which are located on different nodes. A wishes to send a message, M, to B. To do so, the Erlang distribution mechanism on A's node first converts M to a binary using term_to_binary, then sends this binary over the network to B's node. B's node then converts it back to an Erlang term using binary_to_term and places it in B's message queue. I want to change the way term_to_binary is called, but this will be completely transparent to A and B, so pattern matching is unaffected.

Comment: hmm..got your question. I have no idea how to do that :( . You should also post this question on erlang nabble community too. You may get an answer to it by some Erlang expert for sure :)

Comment: Thanks ArunMu, I'll try that.  Thanks for the responses! :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the code correctly, message encoding hardcoded around [the line 1565 of dist.c/dsig_send()](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/erts/emulator/beam/dist.c#L1565) so you can't change the way messages are encoded without patching and recompiling the emulator.

However you can change the carrier for message distribution as described [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/alt_dist.html). There is [an example of use SSL for Erlang distribution](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/ssl_distribution.html). So you can create a connection which compress all transmission messages (maybe it's even possible with tweaked SSL example).

There are few examples of standard distribution modules:

- [inet_tcp_dist.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/kernel/src/inet_tcp_dist.erl)
- [inet6_tcp_dist.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/kernel/src/inet6_tcp_dist.erl)
- [inet_ssl_dist.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/lib/ssl/src/inet_ssl_dist.erl)
- [uds_dist](https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/dev/lib/kernel/examples) example

Comment: OK, thanks! That certainly answers my question, and your idea of implementing an alternative distribution carrier is interesting... I'll look into that.  Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rpc from node to node? Or OTP behaviours? if so try to compress with zlib the binary before it is sent